# GridView does not update DataTable

Tags: vb.net, gridview, datatable, dataset, devexpress

I am using a DevExpress XtraGrid/View for windows forms. The datasource of the grid is a binding source, which is connected to a dataset. My problem is, this table adapter does not update the datatable. I can insert new rows without problems, but I can't update. No error message is thrown; when I save changes, the row value just reverts. This happens for every column in the row. Here is my code for saving and then reloading data:

```
            ' Class variable
            Private _invoiceDetailsAdapter As dsInvoiceDetailsTableAdapters.inv_InvoiceDetailsTableAdapter = New dsInvoiceDetailsTableAdapters.inv_InvoiceDetailsTableAdapter()

            'Save Data
            InvInvoiceLineBindingSource.EndEdit()
            _invoiceDetailsAdapter.Update(DsInvoiceDetails.inv_InvoiceDetails)

            'Load
            DsInvoiceDetails.inv_InvoiceDetails.Clear()
            If Me._invoiceId > 0 Then
                _invoiceDetailsAdapter.Fill(DsInvoiceDetails.inv_InvoiceDetails, _invoiceId)
                InvInvoiceLineBindingSource.Sort = "LineNum"
            End If
```

I've figured out that it must be the dataset itself, because I've tried using a regular DataGridView with the dataset, to no avail. I generated the dataset through the wizard and had to add ColumnName and SourceColumn properties in the parameters for Insert & Update. The parameters for Insert & Update look identical as far as properties are concerned.

I've also tried creating new datasets, datatables, binding sources and tableadapters. I've even tried a DataAdapter but there was no difference. I have literally spent 2 weeks now looking through the properties and debugging, trying to find a cause.

Can someone please offer some advice?

Comment: It seems it is updated only when moving to a new row after making the change. If I don't change rows it doesn't update, hence why I can insert. Weirdest thing, most likely a bug in some other place. Still looking. Let me know if you have anything I can try though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was DevExpress' XtraGrid functionality.

`The XtraGrid does not immediately save an edit value to the linked dataset. The modified row is usually posted to the data object when focus is moved to another grid row. You can programmatically force the update by calling the UpdateCurrentRow method. In your case you should only call the CloseEditor and UpdateCurrentRow methods before updating the dataset via the DB adapter object.`

So if a user only updates only one row, those changes go *nowhere.* Read on for a code snippet...

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A327